# How to change package name of apk file developed in andromo?

Tags: android, android-intent

I built an Android app in [Andromo](http://www.andromo.com/) and uploaded to play store. Now I want to upload the second version of the app. So I developed again the same app in [Andromo](http://www.andromo.com/) with some advanced features. Now problem is that the first name of the package is different from the second one. I used APK Studio and changed the package name, but it did not work.
(Andromo just provides APK, not source code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change package name for already published app.

[Further reading...](http://android-developers.blogspot.ae/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html)

Comment: No sir,I want to apply package name of the uploaded app to second app's apk(new version of the uploaded app).